# Problem with multioutput bidirectional lstm

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm a newbie for programming the multi-output classification for text classification but when I tried to compile my model there was some error:

> Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 4 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays:

How should I solve this problem and is there a mistake in my model?

I tried to fixing the labeling and data preprocessing but the error still happens.

I have 4 labels `(LA,LB,LC,LD)`.

Shape of `x_train` tensor: `(201, 525)`

Label Example : 
`[array([[1.],[4.],[4.],[4.],[4.],[2.]]), array([[2.],[3.]......)....]`

```py
def LSTMmodel(hiddenlayer = 64, drop = 0.5):
    #Input
    sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')

    ########################################################################
    embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)
    print (embedded_sequences)
    dropout = Dropout(drop)(embedded_sequences)

    #########################################################################


    y1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer, return_sequences=True))(dropout)
    y1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer, return_sequences=True))(y1)
    y1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer, return_sequences=True))(y1)
    y1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer))(y1)
    y1 = Dropout(drop)(y1)

    y2 =  Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer, return_sequences=True))(dropout)
    y2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer, return_sequences=True))(y2)
    y2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer, return_sequences=True))(y2)
    y2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer))(y2)
    y2 = Dropout(drop)(y2)

    y3 =  Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer, return_sequences=True))(dropout)
    y3 = Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer, return_sequences=True))(y3)
    y3 = Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer, return_sequences=True))(y3)
    y3 = Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer))(y3)
    y3 = Dropout(drop)(y3)

    y4 =  Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer, return_sequences=True))(dropout)
    y4 = Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer, return_sequences=True))(y4)
    y4 = Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer, return_sequences=True))(y4)
    y4 = Bidirectional(LSTM(hiddenlayer))(y4)
    y4 = Dropout(drop)(y4)

    y1 = Dense(LA_nodes, activation='softmax',name= 'LA')(y1)
    y2 = Dense(LB_nodes, activation='softmax',name= 'LB')(y2)
    y3 = Dense(LC_nodes, activation='softmax',name= 'LC')(y3)
    y4 = Dense(LD_nodes, activation='softmax',name= 'LD')(y4)




    model = Model(sequence_input,outputs =[y1,y2,y3,y4])
    model.summary()


    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01,momentum=0.9),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])


    checkloss = create_checkpoint('LSTM') 
    checkacc = create_checkpoint2('LSTM')


    print('Training...')
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_trainn_new,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=max_epochs,
              validation_data=x_test,
              shuffle=True,
              #callbacks=[checkloss, checkacc, early_stopping])
    return model, history
```

I expect there is no  value error but it still on

Comment: Well, the error message is quite self explanatory. Your model has 4 outputs,  so `fit` expects a list (plain python list) of 4 numpy arrays. But you are  giving it only one numpy array

Comment: Try changing the Input targe to one-hot vectors